# HTTP Error 500 PHP

Tags: php, pdo

I am getting an HTTP Error 500 on my website. The PHP code checker doesn't see anything suspicious.
I think it's caused by PDO but I'm not sure because when I remove all the PHP code it still gives me the same error.
Here's my code:
Index.php:

```
<?php
    include_once('includes/db_connect.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable="no>
    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <!-- Optional theme (flatly) -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/latest/flatly/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <!-- Font awesome -->
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/latest/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/contact.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/contact.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <title><?php
        foreach($dbh->query('SELECT * FROM page_info') as $row) {
            echo $row['title'];
        }
        ?></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="banner">
        <div class="name"><?php
        foreach ($dbh->query('SELECT * FROM page_info') as $row) {
            echo $row[“name”];
        }
                ?></div>
    </div>
    <div class="about">
        <div class="about-container">
            <div class="about-main-text">
                <h1>About me:</h1>
                <?php
                    foreach ($dbh->query('SELECT * FROM about') as $row) {
                    echo '
                        <span>'.$row["text"].'</span>
                    ';
                }
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="projects">
        <div class="projects-container">
            <div class="projects-main-text">
                <h1>My projects:</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <?php
                  foreach($dbh->query('SELECT * FROM projects') as $row) {
                      echo '
                            <div class="col-md-4 nopadding">
                                 <div class="project-box">
                                      <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $row['image'] ).'" alt="Project Image">
                                      <h1>'.$row["name"].'</h1>
                                      <p>'.$row["desc"].'</p>
                                 </div>
                            </div>
                      ';
                  }
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="contact">
        <div class="contact-container">
            <div class="contact-main-text">
                <h1>Contact me:</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <form action="contact/send.php" method="post" style="float: left;">
                    <div class="field name-box">
                        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Who Are You?"/>
                        <label for="name">Name</label>
                        <span class="ss-icon">check</span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="field email-box">
                        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="name@email.com"/>
                        <label for="email">Email</label>
                        <span class="ss-icon">check</span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="field msg-box">
                        <textarea id="msg" rows="4" placeholder="Your message goes here..."/></textarea>
                        <label for="msg">Msg</label>
                        <span class="ss-icon">check</span>
                    </div>

                    <input class="button" type="submit" value="Send" />
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <span class="copyright">
            &copy; <?php
                foreach ($dbh->query('SELECT * FROM page_info') as $row) {
                    echo $row['copyright'];
                }
            echo ' ' . date("Y");
?> - All rights reserved
        </span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is db_connect.php:

```
<?php

    $uname = ‘rik_root’;
    $upass = ‘*********’;

    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=nijdeken’, $uname, $upass);

?>
```

I hope someone can help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's with the curly apostrophes?

Comment: Activate the error message on a local server and then try it, you'll see exactly what the error 500 is. In php.ini, use this: display_errors = On

Comment: Please add logs from the server

Comment: Where? It works local with mamp but it is not working on my web server

Comment: HTTP 500 is a generic error message. Can you look into the error logs and see if you can find any specific information? If you are using cpanel then log into cpanel and check 'Error Logs'.

Comment: @YannChabot I have a host that doesn't give me access to he php.ini because I'm on a shared server

Comment: @RaghavendraN I have checked all the log files and it doesnt say anything suspicious.

Comment: @Rik can you try the code on a local server? Or do you have access to error log

Comment: `‘ ’` those are choking your code. use regular quotes `'`.

Comment: @YannChabot It all works on my local server but when I migrate all the code to the web server it doesn't work anymore. I can't find anything in the log fikes

Comment: @Fred-ii- I changed it but it still doesn't work

Comment: what about this `echo $row[“name”];` ?

Comment: error reporting would have helped you here. when you code, don't use a word processor; use a "code editor".

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a word processor to edit your code:

```
$uname = ‘rik_root’;
         ^--------^
```

those are not valid php quote characters, and are probably killing your code with a fatal parse error:

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=nijdeken’, $uname, $upass);
               ^--start of string                   ^--NOT an end-of-string
```

Comment: same thing goes for `[“name”]` - I didn't venture far enough in their code to see it.